# cannot find file -lfile_system boost

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to test my boost installation with this code from [here](https://tabreziqbal.wordpress.com/2006/03/16/how-to-test-c-boost-installation/)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>

namespace bfs=boost::filesystem;

int main()
{
    bfs::path p("second.cpp");

    if(bfs::exists(p))

    std::cout<<p.leaf()<<std::endl;
}
```

On Ubuntu 16.04 the full error is

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfile_system
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I've looked in /usr/bin/ld the file does not exist and would like to know if I need to fix the boost installation or is their a linking problem that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the Boost filesystem library is boost_filesystem, so you need to link with:

```
-lboost_filesystem
```

(has always been in a system installation, can be more complex with a custom installation).

`file_system` was never the name of a Boost library.

Comment: Thanks this web page gave -lfile_system. Just in case any one else comes across this the full command that worked was                                                        g++ -g second.cpp -o second -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem